# How to add Monaco editor to reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I installed
`npm install Monaco-editor`
but its showing me error.

How to correct it?                                            .

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
just run this one.

```
npm install @monaco-editor/react Monaco-editor
```

Comment: you don't need the "Monaco-editor" argument.

`npm install @monaco-editor/react` would do.